# <script> tags inside an <asp:repeater>

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I'm outputting a few lines of Javascript within a Repeater control on an ASPX page. I want to use a value from my DataSource inside the script tag.

A very basic example might be:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterBlah" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
   Hello <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomeName")%>
   <script>myfunction(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomeNumber")%>)</script>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm aware that most people won't repeat script tags like this, but I am using a small snippet of code from a third-party that you can place anywhere on a page to create a Flash object. You pass it a number so it knows which image gallery to display. No problems using several on one page.

To begin with, this worked fine, although I noticed the colours in Visual Web Developer indicated that it didn't really like the `<%#` being used inside a `<script>` tag. Intellisense was going a bit nuts in the code-behind too!

So what is the correct way to pass Dataset items into a script tag?

Comment: show your example with the text box.  Perhaps the error was introduced when you added it.

Comment: I don't know, but it would make sense that you can't access the text box server control since it doesn't really exist except as a template.  To get at it, you would probably have to handle the databinding event or go through the template.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the mention of TextBox, that turned out to be irrelevant.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What error you get?

Comment: Intellisense is misbehaving, so I find it hard to see what the true problem is. I guess what I am asking is; what is the correct way to pass the number from the DataSet to the script tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This perhaps? (Can't quite remember if the + signs should in fact be & signs though)

```
<%# "<script>myfunction(" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomeNumber") + ")</script>" %>
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that. It does work, and Intellisense moans less. I was mainly wondering what the 'proper' way of doing this was!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative syntax would be the following:

```
<%# Eval("SomeNumber", "<script>myfunction({0});</script>") %>
```

This uses the optional parameter where you can supply a format string.